# Importing Cookies with Mechanize

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize, cookielib

(Using Python 2.7, with Mechanize)

Let's say I have a cookie on Twitter, named `auth_token` and it's Value is: `ABC123`.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/de568907c939617c14a874696664aeeb.png]

How do tell `Mechanize` to import this Cookie? I've heard about `Cookielib` but I am not sure how to use it. I looked it up, but I've no clue how to set this up with `Mechanize`.

If someone could help me out, that would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
cookie = cookielib.Cookie(auth_token='ABC123')
cookiejar.set_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Nope, I got :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 14, in <module>
    cookie = cookielib.Cookie(auth_token='ABC123')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_token'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it as HTTP headers

```
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('Cookie','name=value')]
```